# SqlDependency.OnChange keep firing

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, sqldependency

from what i understood,SqlDependency.OnChange should only fire when the query result changes
here is a small application, i placed a counter inside the event, and displayed it, it seem like it continuously fire even if i didnt add new rows, i tried some examples from some blogs, and i get the same results, what am i doing wrong?
i checked "sys.transmission_queue" and "sys.dm_qn_subscriptions" both were empty
the SqlNotificationEventArgs properties value are "Info = Invalid,Source = Statement,Type = Subscribe"

```
    private void Runnn()
    {
        var query = from x in Entities.Contacts select x;
        qqq.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
        con = new SqlConnection(@"server=PC\sqlexpress08;
             database=test2db;Trusted_Connection=yes;");
        command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID,Name FROM dbo.Contacts",con);
        BeginSqlDependency(con.ConnectionString);
        
    }
    private void BeginSqlDependency(string connection)
    {
        SqlDependency.Stop(connection);
        SqlDependency.Start(connection);
        RegisterSqlDependency();
    }
    private void RegisterSqlDependency()
    {
        
        command.Notification = null;
        dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
        dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(DependencyOnChange);
        RegisterSqlCommand();
    }
    private void RegisterSqlCommand()
    {
        con.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    private void DependencyOnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDependency dependency = (SqlDependency)sender;
        dependency.OnChange -= DependencyOnChange;
        var query = from x in Entities.Contacts select x;
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, _
             new Action(() => { qqq.ItemsSource = null; qqq.ItemsSource = 
             query.ToList(); ee.Text = i.ToString(); }));
        RegisterSqlDependency();
        i++;
    }
    ##SQL server Express SP2 2008##
    ALTER DATABASE test2db SET ENABLE_BROKER; 
    CREATE QUEUE ContactChangeMessages;
    CREATE SERVICE ContactChangeNotifications
    ON QUEUE ContactChangeMessages
    ([http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostQueryNotification]);
```

Comment: You are looking in the wrong queue. `command.Notification` is null so it's using a default queue name. [See VB example here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190270%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Today I had exactly the same issue and for me the problem was relating to set options, note that you can see what is the error by putting a break point in  your **DependencyOnChange** event handler and watching the **SqlNotificationEventArgs** info property (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details)

Registering a query for Query Notification requires the database connection on which the subscription is made to have the correct SET OPTIONS enabled:

```
ANSI_NULLS ON 
ANSI_PADDING ON 
ANSI_WARNINGS ON 
CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON 
QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF 
ARITHABORT ON
```

and you turn ARITHABORT on in Sql Studio Management's database property dialog (see [here](http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=3144) for more details).

Also, consider the following steps if you want to enable service broker (Northwind is database name)

```
ALTER DATABASE Northwind SET enable_broker WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
ALTER DATABASE Northwind SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::Northwind TO [sa]
```

Answer (score 1):

Other things to consider that would cause SqlDependency to continuously fire:

1. Using a query that is not specific (i.e. No wildcards "*", or DISTINCT usage).
2. Not using a fully qualified table name (ex: SELECT Person FROM PersonTable vs. SELECT Person FROM **dbo**.PersonTable).